# Process size growing in multi thread application

Tags: c++, multithreading

I need some solution to figure out the issue.
New and delete in different threads in my application after processing more number of request the process size growing and not coming down.

Psudo code:

```
Main () {
    Thread1 enter
    Creating object and inserting into map.
    Thread1 exit

    Thread2 enter
    Itherating to the map and creating child thread based on the no of object in the map.
    Thread2 exit

    Child thread calling the function at the end deleting the object.
}
```

Object created in Thread1 deleted in child thread spawned using Thread2.

Is the above approcach is fine. Am i making any mistakes.
Because when the number of object increased in map.
Process size grows rapidly even after deleting all the allocated object and clearing the map.
 Can anyone tell me what could be the reason for process size growth.
Update:

---

Had an update. I have checked the process with libumem tool which is leak detector. Shows nothing.

When the incoming traffic and deletion rate is equal process size not grown.
Process size increasing only under heavy traffic.
Example:
Incoming traffic rate is 4000 and deletion rate is 100
The process size grows.
After all the request processed and deleted expected the process size back to normal but not coming back to normal.
One more observation is 1st time i am sending 10k request
Memory increased not coming down
Then i am sending again 10k request this time process size not increased.
The increased memory on the 1st iteration was reused.
Is it related to OS behavior?

Comment: Don't use new and delete.  Their misuse causes memory leaks.  Use smart pointers instead if you really need dynamic allocation.

Comment: If you must use new and delete, look up a memory profiler like valgrind

Comment: Are you putting a pointer to the object in the map, or copying the object into the map?

Comment: Is the approach fine? Creating transient threads smells odd, it's rarely the best way to use them. Are you making any mistakes? If so, they're probably in your implementation, which you haven't shown (although admittedly an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for threaded code isn't easy)

Comment: EvilTeach ,i am putting the object inside map

Comment: @user one would suspect that as more and more object are inserted into the map, that the map would continue to grow.  They don't shrink automatically.

Answer (score 2):

This is how standard library manages the memory. 
Acquirement of memory from system is quite expensive, so it is not returned to system immediately since there is a big chance it will be needed again soon.

Threads are also not disposed immediately since creating them is expensive process. So when `std::thread` is done actual thread is just moved to a thread pool to be reused in a future.

This standard library behavior is quite broad and complex.

But if your programs keeps growing constantly (do not stop at some level),
then you must have a memory leak in your application. 
In such case I recommend use some tools to detect memory leaks, for example clang address sanitizer is great.